# Overpy returning attribute error upon import

Tags: python, overpass-api, nominatim

I've been testing some code utilizing overpy before christmas and now it's giving me an attribute error. Is anyone else having this issue? Or is my console corrupted?

Code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import overpy

api = overpy.Overpass()

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
location = geolocator.geocode(input('Enter location:'))


cords = (location.latitude, location.longitude, location.latitude, location.longitude)


result = api.query("node"+f'{cords}'+";out;")

node = result.nodes[0]
print(node.id)
print(location.latitude)
print(location.longitude)
```

Returns

```
AttributeError: module 'overpy' has no attribute 'Overpass
```

Documentation linked here

https://readthedocs.org/projects/python-overpy/downloads/pdf/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded Python natively and ran with Pycharm and it worked, may be an issue with my anaconda.

Thanks